# linux + activate some script after linux reboot

Tags: linux

I have Linux 5.3 redhat
I want to add the script add_dhcp.ksh to my Linux machine in order to update ifcfg-eth1 automatically after reboot ( this script enable dhcp and startup eth1 )

my question:
please advice the steps that needed in order to activate automatically the add_dhcp.ksh script after Linux  reboot ,

```
    add_dhcp.ksh script

    #!/bin/ksh


    perl -i -pe "s/none/dhcp/"  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 
    perl -i -pe "s/no/yes/"  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 
    ifdown eth1
    ifup   eth1
```

Comment: Is eth1's config not saved after rebooting? Moreover, why did you edit eth1 and restart eth0?

Comment: sorry my mistake see update

Comment: What is your final goal? Why did you need to change it at boot?

Comment: actually this script is example of change some conf in Linux after reboot , my final script will be different with allot of configuration include network configuration , so I dont want to show here complicated script ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this script by adding it to /etc/rc.local file.
whatever is present in rc.local file, it is run by linux at every startup.the order is fine, its just that you can use "service network restart" instead of ifup ifdown.
.
also, what is the need to do this manually at every reboot? why not permantally enable DHCP on this interface once?

Comment: hi Frank , I prefer to add the script under directory and not to edit any file , did you have other solution

Comment: There is no directory in linux, which is confugred this way to run commands atr startup, but just files.

Comment: Adding a file in /etc/cron.d with an appropriate entry would do this

Comment: lain: Cron only runs scripts at specific time, it does not recognized startup, shutodwn or reboots.

Comment: @Frank: I suggest you go look at the man page for a modern cron/crontab(5) `@reboot   :    Run once, at startup.`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using cron and the @reboot 'time' in /etc/crontab e.g.

```
@reboot root /path/to/add_dhcp.ksh
```

This will run your command once at startup.

EDIT:

If you don't want to edit any existing system files then you can create a file in /etc/cron.d. This directory is like an extension to the /etc/crontab file and the files use the same format. Note that files in this directory should be writeable only by root.

Create file (`/etc/cron.d/rebootfixup` for example) and add a line like this

```
@reboot root /path/to/add_dhcp.ksh
```

Now when your system boot the file will be added to the list of cron jobs and actioned appropriately.

Comment: crontab -l
no crontab for root ( I cant use crontab -:( )

Comment: @Diana See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual way to do this is to drop it into rc.local, but if you don't want to change files and want a pure directory approach, you *can* put your script into the /etc/init.d directory. Configure it to accept an argument of 'start' or 'stop' (the stop arg may not be relevant to this particular use case though). Then add a symlink in /etc/rc3.d/ to point to your script with a name of, for example, S99adddhcp.

These 'rc' directories are read as part of the startup process, and you can modify startup behaviors here if you like this method over rc.local for some reason.

Here are a couple of many, many references to this type of configuration - well worth reading:

http://www.notesbit.com/index.php/scripts-unix/customizing-system-startup-in-redhat-linux/
http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/

--Matt